# Maven3 child project does not reference from `pluginManagement` but inherit from parent project

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml

### My project tree like

```
parent project (plugin A: version=1.0)
  child project (pluginManagement(plugin A: version=2.0), (plugin A: without version))
```

#### example

parent

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
</plugin>
```

child

```xml
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
...
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

The final version 2.22.2 will be used

And I can not change the parent `pom.xml`, it like a `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

How can I use the version specified by `pluginManagement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not specifying the version in the `<plugins>` section of the parent POM. Use `<pluginManagement>` in the parent POM.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I have no right to change the parent pom file, it like a `spring-boot-starter-parent`

Comment: Then you cannot use `pluginManagement` to override the version, you need to set it directly in the `<plugin>` definition in `<plugins>`.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks weird to me if it is the only way.

Comment: Direct definitions are always stronger than `pluginManagement`. This is also true for direct definitions in the parent POM.